# Salvar resposta da requisão á API como arquivo JSON

Tags: json, get, http-request, requisição

Ao fazer uma requisição a URL(API), o resultado dela é um JSON. Como posso salvar esse JSON em um arquivo.json localmente na minha máquina?
Meu código até o momento:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://urldaapi");
xhr.send();
console.log(xhr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar essa função, alterando apenas a sua url:

```
(function (fetch, console) {
    fetch('https://urldaapi')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.save(data));

    console.save = function (data, filename) {

        if (!data) {
            console.error('Console.save: No data')
            return;
        }

        if (!filename) filename = 'console.json'

        if (typeof data === "object") {
            data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4);
        }

        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
            e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
            a    = document.createElement('a');

        a.download = filename;
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':');
        e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        a.dispatchEvent(e);
    };

}).call(this, window.fetch, window.console || {});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Depois de ter salvado o arquivo como faço pra acessar um valor desse arquivo alterá-lo e salva-lo novamente? Preciso manipular os valores desse arquivo